# Mysterious 2-Second Black Screen Every 18 Seconds Issue: MacBook Air A1932 (EMC 3184)

Tags: battery, charging, power

**Problem:**

I am experiencing an interesting issue with a MacBook Air A1932 (EMC 3184). If the battery is depleted, I get the display to connect the charger, but if there is some charge to the battery, a black display comes on for two (2) seconds. If the lid remains open, the black screen comes on for two (2) seconds every eighteen (18) seconds.

**What I have tried: No result**

Resetting the the NVRAM, PRAM, and SMC

I would appreciate some assistance on how I could go about fixing this problem?